# One Atosys job to run on 2 machines

Tags: autosys

I have 2 windows machines and one Unix machine.  On Unix machine autosys JILS are defined. 
I have one cleanup job, that I want to run on both the windows machine @ same time every day.
I don’t want to create 2 different jobs (JIL’s). In JIL can I add two machine names like machine: WindowMachine1, WindowMachine2 , is this correct or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the AutoSys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Defining multiple machines as a single virtual entity will cause AutoSys to treat them as a pool and load balance when sending them work, causing your cleanup job to only run on one of the two machines.

To have a job run on both machines simultaneously, you will need two separate CMD jobs, one sent to each machine.